# Keep Form Data after TemplateResponse

Tags: python, html, django

Is There any way to keep the input data by user after submitting form ( Django / Python / HTML )

I put the input data one by one in dictionary then use TemplateResponse in the view to return dictionary , in HTML i use {{dict}} but it is not the optimum way

Part of View

```
if(request.GET.get('mybtn')):

        if str(request.GET.get('tech')) == "2G":
                        dic = {}
            dic['productname'] = str(request.GET.get('productname'))
                        # After calculation get price and should be returned  
            dic['price'] = "50"

            return TemplateResponse(request,'cell.html',dic)
```

Part of HTML

```
<input style="width: 80%;"  type="text" name="productname" required value={{ productname }}> 

<label for="price">{{ price }}</label>
```

however , it is expected to return the price only and keep the view of the  product name which is already entered
as in the real case there are a lot of inputs and selections

Comment: This is what the Django forms framework does; you should use it. (Also, why are you using TemplateResponse directly?)

Comment: What should I use instead of TemplateResponse?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this here?

python:

```
dic_productname = ""
dic_price = ""

if(request.GET.get('mybtn')):

        if str(request.GET.get('tech'))=="2G":
                        dic={}
            dic_productname=str(request.GET.get('productname'))
                        # After calculation get price and should be returned  
            dic_price="50"

            return render_template('cell.html', dic_productname = dic_productname, dic_price=dic_price)
```

html:

```
<input style="width: 80%;"  type="text" name="productname" required value={{dic_productname}}> 

<label for="price">{{dic_price}}</label>
```